# Laravel htaccess trouble

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my `index.php` file one directory above framework folder.

So, I have two versions of `htaccess` file each with its own troubles:

1. The Laravel friendly `htaccess`:

Works perfectly for Laravel, but when my link is shared on Facebook, it becomes `www.myqourse.com/www.mqourse.com/..../.../...` etc.

```
# Use PHP56 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56s .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

2. The no issues version for Facebook and Twitter:

Doesn't load resources (`.js` or `.css`) but Facebook and Twitter can only get a clean link.

```
# Use PHP56 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56s .php

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php) [NC,F]
```

Any help?

Comment: properly not an issue of htaccess, but your share link incorrectly setup

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly forgot to remove pretender.io from Kernel.php as a global variable 6 months ago. I did it locally, but forgot to push to the server that one particular file :/